# Select from local SQL Server Compact Edition database using linq

Tags: c#, sql, select, sql-server-ce

I get the following error about my select query:

[image]

Here is the select query in question:

```
public int countLogin(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        int query = (from a in de.userlogin
                     where a.username == username && a.password == password
                     select a).Count();
        return query;   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The error said that `ntext` cannot be used with `order by` or `where` clause. Therefore, I am not using `ntext` data type in my database scheme

[image]

So where did I go wrong ? because there is no `varchar` data type
[image]

i think this is some bugs, according to the following [url](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958478#appliesto)

Comment: This is not at all an answer to your question, but are you storing passwords as plain text? I really hope not. Please, PLEASE don't do that. Passwords should be salted and hashed before storing. If you don't know what that means, post a reply to this comment and I'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: currently, i want to store password as plain text, now, i want to select the data from database, and found error like i have mentioned above

Comment: are you using any entity frameworks/models/etc?  If so, remember to refresh them after you change your database, so your program actually picks up the changes.

Comment: @RussellUhl yep, i am using ado.net model

Comment: Are you using EF6 with the latest SQL Server Compact EF provider? I think not, as this issue should be solved then.

Comment: @ErikEJ where can i get one ?

Comment: Use Nuget: EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact or EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy

Answer (score 0):

ntext is used to be nvarchar(count or MAX).

Try using varchar(100) instead of nvarchar(100).

Greetz

Comment: i am using sql express 2008, there's only ntext, nvarchar, nchar for string datatype, which one would you recommend to store password ?

Comment: Show us the class definiton of your "de" object please.

Comment: i am not using any class definition, i just create the `ado.net` object

Comment: Mhm, actually you should be able to set the datatype to char or varchar, because n(char/-varchar) means you got a unicode string. Maybe you switch to the normal SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I don't know if the express version lacks of that ability, but I can't believe that.

And if you are able, then change the nvarchar to varchar.

Comment: you probably should consider not storing the password in clear text

Comment: Yea thought him to use encryption like AES256 or 512, but for that reason a (n)varchar(MAX) column would be appropriate.

Comment: @trickzter i have changed the datatype in my database into nvarchar, and stil returning the same error

Comment: @Trickzter AES is two-way encryption and not appropriate for storing a password. One-way with SHA-3 or similar is a much better approach. Salt and hash the password, then store it. When authenticating a user, salt and hash the provided password and then compare THAT to what is stored in the database.

Comment: @RickLiddle Yea right, one-way would make more sense.

Cignitor You should change the column type to "varchar" not "nvarchar".

Comment: @Trickzter there is no varchar datatype, see the updated thread, i have post some screenshot

Comment: "Not all data types in SQL Server are supported in SQL Server CE. For example, non-Unicode text columns (varchar, char, text) and smallmoney are not supported; although nvarchar, nchar, ntext, and money are supported." Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275635(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @RickLiddle Thanks mate, that's the point. That's why I suggested to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 full version.